# Android Java visual Clipboard in TextInpuLayout with a big Background

Tags: android, clipboard

I'm using a TextInpuLayout in an Alertdialog for creating a custom Input Dialog.
Everything Works fine but when I'm using the visual Clipboard of Android 13 to Copy or Paste some Text,
then the Clipboard has a big Frame cover the hole Dialog.
If I using an Editview inside a "normal" Activity everything looks normal.
My TextInpuLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And so it looks when I open the Clipboard:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrhrR.png)

I can't fix it.
(Sorry it's my first Post).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find it out by myself.
It was this entry in my Dialog Theme:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/colorBGListgreen</item>
```

I removed this and put this in a drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorBGList"/>
</shape>
```

And use in in my showDialog Method:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(dialog1.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_background);
```

After doing this it works fine